# How can i bind dynamic array data to multiselect?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using a bootstrap multiselect plugin by david stutz.

Here is my html

```
<select class="multiselect" name="multiselect[]" id="multiselect-employee" ng-model="taskData.AssignedId" ng-options="emp.Name for emp in employeelistoptions" multiple="multiple" multiselect-dropdown></select>
```

here is my script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add-new-task').on('click', function () {       
        $('#multiselect-employee').multiselect({
            nonSelectedText: 'Select an employee!',
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            enableFiltering: true
       });   
        clearValues(scope);
    });
});
```

employeelist options is a dynamic array which stores data

```
 $scope.employeelistoptions =[ {
    ProfileId:0 ,
    Name: ""
       }];
```

Now the multiselect doesn't works if employeelistoptions is used. but it works when some array like employeeList(Which is not dynamic) is used.

```
$scope.employeeList = [{
        ProfileId: 1,
        Name: "Antony"
    }, {
        ProfileId: 2,
        Name: "Amal"
    }, {
    ProfileId: 3,
    Name: "Sachin"
}];
```

How can i bind dynamic array data to multiselect?